# How to replace multiple substring at once and not sequentially?

Tags: python, string

I want to replace multiple substring at once, for instance, in the following statement I want to replace dog with cat and cat with dog:

I have a dog but not a cat.

However, when I use sequential replace `string.replace('dog', 'cat')` and then `string.replace('cat', 'dog')`, I get the following.

I have a dog but not a dog.

I have a long list of replacements to be done at once so a nested replace with temp will not help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by nested replace.

string.replace('dog', 'tmptmptmp') 
string.replace('cat', 'dog')
string.replace('tmptmptmp', 'cat') 

Is the correct solution. Also "Done at once" isn't very specific, as unless you are working in multiple threads it's not being done at the same time. Even if you are you just need a random long string  for each replacement.

Comment: I know this solution, i.e., string.replace('dog', 'tmptmptmp').replace('cat','dog').replace('tmptmptmp', 'cat') in one line. How do I do this if I have 100s of such replacements to be done?

Comment: Why can't you do this one after another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way using `re.sub`:

```
import re

string = "I have a dog but not a cat."

d = {"dog": "cat", "cat": "dog"}
new_string = re.sub("|".join(d), lambda x: d[x.group(0)], string)
```

Output:

```
'I have a cat but not a dog.'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replace('dog', '#temp').replace('cat', 'dog').replace('#temp', 'cat')
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using count occurrences:

```
words = 'I have a dog but not a cat'
words = words.replace('cat', 'dog').replace('dog', 'cat', 1)
print(words)

# I have a cat but not a dog
```

Comment: Won't work for `I have a dog dog but not a cat cat`.